# SQL sum across large number of tables

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Our current database has data spread out in a table-per-store structure at the moment, such that there can be thousands of tables for a particular schema.

Each table has pretty basic data (transactions) and looks like:

```
store1_table:
| id | total_revenue | net_profit | date |
| 1  | 25            | 5          |      |
| 2  | 36            | 10         |      |
| 3  | 20            | 7          |      |
```

I'm trying to get the total sales for all stores, over a specific time period.

For a single store the performance is quite reasonable, but when I try to query the total across all the tables (hundreds, or maybe thousands), the performance slows down significantly.

For the SQL query I'm using SQLAlchemy, but it's generating a reasonable simple query e.g.:

```
viewport = union_all(*hundredsOfTables)
session.query(func.sum(viewport.c.net_profit))
```

Is it the UNION ALL that is causing the performance issue, the structure of our database, or is there a better approach to retrieving this sum of all tables' netprofit?

Comment: The solution is to store the data in a single table, with an additional column identifying the `store`.  I imagine that the `union all` makes it harder for the optimizer to generate an efficient plan for the query.  You might consider running a job each night to combine all the data into a single table for analytic purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. Will look into keeping data in a single table with a column specifying store_id.

Answer (score 1):

Suspecting that the `union_all` across so many tables is actually a problem, try to aggregate on single table-level first, and then sum up intermediate results:

```
# get list of sum-queries for all tables
sub_queries = [session.query(func.sum(_.c.net_profit).label("sub_net"))
               for _ in hundredsOfTables]

# create a union subquery
u = sub_queries[0].union_all(*sub_queries[1:])
u = u.subquery("tmp")
# create a query which gets the grand-total
t = session.query(func.sum(u.c.sub_net)).scalar()
print(t)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I'm not sure if it's because some tables have a small number of rows, and some have a large amount - but the performance was very similar for both.

We may investigate if keeping a unified table of all data helps with performance, although this may lead to some data duplication. I'm guessing having a single table may allow better optimization by the database for indexes?

Comment: I do not know, and you should definitely analyse the query execution itself (*Query Analyser* in MS SQL Server , `EXPLAIN ANALYSE query` for postgresql) and see where the database engine needs help.